# Copy paste as values Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code but I need it to copy paste the data as values. I know it probably is very simple, but I have not used .Paste function, so I do not know how to convert it. I am at a very beginner level. Many thanks in advance!

```
Sub Movetabletototal()
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim copyRng As Range, pasteRng As Range
    Dim totalWS As Worksheet, mixerWS As Worksheet

    Set totalWS = Worksheets("TOTAL")
    Set mixerWS = Worksheets("MIXER TOTAL")

    Set copyRng = mixerWS.Range("P3:Q" & mixerWS.Cells(mixerWS.Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).Row)

    Dim newRow As Long
    newRow = totalWS.Cells(totalWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If newRow > 1 Then newRow = newRow + 1

    copyRng.Copy totalWS.Range(totalWS.Cells(newRow, 1), totalWS.Cells(newRow + copyRng.Rows.Count, copyRng.Columns.Count))
End Sub
```

Comment: Read `PasteSpecial` Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[`PasteSpecial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx)** in your code. Change the last line to this:

```
'.
'. Your code will be the same till here
'.

copyRng.Copy

Set pasteRng = totalWS.Range(totalWS.Cells(newRow, 1), _
totalWS.Cells(newRow + copyRng.Rows.Count, copyRng.Columns.Count))

pasteRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Or you can use values like below (set the ranges like above):

```
pasteRng.Value = copyRng.Value
```

Comment: How about using .value=.value instead copy-paste?

Comment: @Vinnie OP asks about using paste function. I personally prefer that method (Just check out my last question here and my own answer to it).

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in the *values* there's no reason to use either `Copy`, `Paste` or `PasteSpecial`. Instead, just use a direct value assignment:

```
Dim destinationRange as Range
With totalWs
    Set destinationRange = .Cells(newRow, 1).Resize(copyRange.Rows.Count, copyRange.Columns.Count)
End With

destinationRange.Value = copyRange.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

.PASTESPECIAL (-4163)

Comment: xlPasteValues = -4163 --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx